# What's the best way to create a unique repeatable identification column with rows that are nearly identicle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm writing a stored procedure that links together data from several different relational tables based on the primary key for the main table. This information is being send to a flat database.  The stored procedure is going to produce several nearly identical rows where only a single column may be different due to multiple entries in some of the tables that are linked to a single entry in the main table.  I need to uniquely identify each row in the stored procedure output but I am unable to use the primary key from the main table since there will be multiple entries for each "key".

I considered taking the approach of using the primary key from the main table followed by each of the columns that may be different in duplicate rows.  For example  _

However, this approach results in a very long and messy key.  I am unable to use a GUID because if any data changes in the relational database the stored procedure is rerun and must update old entries rather than create new ones.

Comment: Sounds like you should be creating a composite primary key made up of the primary keys of the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is only to have a unique key that is as short as possible and does not relate to anything else, consider just adding ROW_NUMBER() to your select.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), othercolumns
```